# Google Drive API changes: "cannot upload content to files of type application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

Tags: google-drive-api

We use Google Drive to store files created by users of [our application](http://storymap.knightlab.com). We've made no change to our Drive application code, and users are now reporting errors "You cannot upload content to files of type application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

This happens to users who have granted our app permissions weeks and months ago, as well as to users who start for the first time today.

Help!

Comment: why the downvote? I'm trying to track down a change in the Google Drive SDK, and this is where the Google Drive SDK team send people for tech support. At least leave some constructive criticism?

Comment: You'll need to post some code. On the face of it, the error message says you're trying to upload content to a Folder, which isn't a valid operation. Paste some code with some evidence that the file you're uploading to is a regular file and not a folder. Better still, an http log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out our code had erroneously been sending the wrong MIME type (application/vnd.google-apps.folder) when creating new folders. It was probably some sort of copy/paste error which had been tolerated by Google all along, until a recent build improved the input checking.

In fact, when [creating a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder), one is only posting JSON metadata (because folders don't have any data of their own), so POSTing the metadata as "application/json" instead of "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Goto your google drive  and create a folder  named

```
Colab Notebooks
```

Then retry the operation of creating a New Notebook.   The error `Google Drive API changes: “cannot upload content to files of type application/vnd.google-apps.folder”` is begin generated because it cannot create the initial directory where the default notebooks are stored.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to the question at all.