# Google Drive sdk make folder result : 400 invalid mime type provided

Tags: delphi, google-drive-api, lazarus

I cannot create folder in google drive with (OAuth - this part is ok) 
App is make in Lazarus (pascalcode), per Ararat synapse libary for net work. 
Access token I have, and to this part is ok.
I can List, Upload, Trash... but below I have problem:

query is sent to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart
method POST and body is

```
{
 "title": "folder",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
 "parents": [
  {
   "id": "root"
  }
 ]
}
```

response is

```
{

     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "Invalid mime type provided"
       }
      ],
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid mime type provided"
     }
    }
```

Any idea, whats I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To create a folder you need to POST to the insert URL. Your code is PUTting to an update content URL. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Answer (score 0):

I think the POST's content type is important and should be **application/json** as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json     <===== IMPORTANT 
...
{
  "title": "pets",
  "parents": [{"id":"0ADK06pfg"}]
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

The mimeType in JSON content is ok.

The hint was here: [Google Drive API changes: “cannot upload content to files of type application/vnd.google-apps.folder”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674803/1022219)

Comment: Ok.  I made reqest as {
  "title": "u-drive",
  "parents": [{"id":"root"}]
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}

Comment: and if I sent request to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart then result was that I must send to /upload..